# models of coins and uniform distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

Here is the sentence which I'm confused with

> Imagine I give you a coin, and want you to estimate the probability it
>   will spin to heads. Given what you know, the most reasonable prior
>   belief is to expect any probability of the coin spinning to heads.
>   This can be captured in a uniform prior on pp, the probability that a
>   coin when spun will land on heads: var p = uniform(0,1).
>
> You conduct an experiment. You spin the coin 20 times. 15 of them,
>   they spin to heads.

I'm confused with the part uniform(0,1). 
why flipping coin prior can be represent with Uniform(0,1)?
I found some related answer here

============================================================

> If random variables (r.v.s) $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are
>   [i.i.d.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables)
>   uniformly distributed on the set $\{0,1\}$, then
>   $\alpha=(0.a_1a_2\ldots)_2$ is a r.v. uniformly distributed on the
>   real interval $[0,1]$. To see this, note that for any
>   $x=(0.x_1x_2\ldots)_2\in[0,1)$ (always taking, WLOG, the unique binary
>   representation of $x$ that has infinitely many $0$s), we have the
>   following:  $$\begin{align}\{\alpha > x\} = & \{a_1>x_1\}\cup\\
> > &\{\{a_1=x_1\}\cap \{a_2>x_2\}\}\cup\\ &\{\{a_1=x_1\}\cap
> > \{a_2=x_2\}\cap\{a_3>x_3\} \}\cup\\ &\ldots \end{align}$$
>
> Now, $P(a_i >x_i) = \frac{1}{2}(1-x_i)$, so the probability of the
>   above disjoint union is just  $$\begin{align}P(\alpha>x) &=
> > \frac{1}{2}(1-x_1) + \frac{1}{2^2}(1-x_2) +
> > \frac{1}{2^3}(1-x_3)+\ldots\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} -
> > \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x_i}{2^i}\\ &= 1 - x\\ \therefore P(\alpha\le
> > x) &= x \end{align} $$ therefore $\alpha$ is a r.v. uniformly
>   distributed on $[0,1]$.

==========================================================
But I'm quite confused with  what is 
$$P(\alpha > x )$$
and why does he concluded 
$$P(\alpha \le x)=x$$
is uniform distribution on [0,1]

Comment: This seems to be a problem given some weighted coin (i.e. you don't know what the probabilities of it landing heads is). This means that any number between $0$ (will never happen) or $1$ (will always happen) is reasonable. Since you want to model this 'belief' about what the probability of heads is then you can model it with a uniform distribution between these values until you can experiment and thus adjust your assumptions about the coin.

Comment: If $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ then the CDF is $P(X \le x) = F_X(x) = x.$ for $0 < x < 1,$ and the PDF is $f_X(x) = 1,$ for $0 < x < 1$ (and $f_X(x) = 0$ elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is intended to be an elementary Bayesian inference problem.
It seems you have decided to let $\theta = P(\text{Heads})$ have the "flat" or "noninformative" 
prior distribution $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1) 
\equiv \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha=1,\beta=1).$ So your prior distribution is 
$p(\theta) = 1.$

> *A uniform prior is not the only possible choice:* (a) If you had some prior experience with or knowledge of the coin, you might
>   choose a prior distribution that reflects your prior opinion. Perhaps you
>   look at the coin, play with it a bit, and decide it seems close to fairly balanced. Then you might choose
>   the prior distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(5,5)$ which puts roughly half of its
>   probability in $(.4, .6)$ [based on a computation in R, where
>   `qbeta(c(.25,.75), 5, 5)` returns 0.3919 and 0.6080.] (b) Another popular
>   choice for a *noninformative* prior is $\mathsf{Beta}(.5, .5).$ 
>   [Google `Jeffrey's priors`.] Your choice of a prior distribution will 
>   influence your final conclusions after you have data and get a posterior
>   distribution. (I think @Twis7ed's Comment is suggesting that priors other than
>   uniform are possible.)

Then from your experiment, you
have $n=20$ Bernoulli trials resulting in $x = 15$ Heads, so your
likelihood function is $p(x|\theta) = \theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}
= \theta^{15}(1-\theta)^5.$

Then according to Bayes' Theorem, the posterior distribution (using the uniform prior) is 
$$p(\theta|x) \propto p(\theta) \times p(x|\theta) \propto \theta^{15}(1-\theta)^5,$$

which we recognize as the kernel (PDF without constant) of $\mathsf{Beta}(16,6).$

The posterior distribution can be used to get a point estimate, which
might be the posterior mean $\frac{16}{16+6} = 0.7272$, posterior median
0.7343 (from R), or posterior mode $\frac{15}{20} = 0.75.$

```
qbeta(.5, 16, 6)
[1] 0.7342603
```

You could also use the posterior distribution to find a Bayesian 95%
probability interval $(0.53, 0.89)$ (from R).

```
qbeta(c(.025, .975), 16, 6)
[1] 0.5283402 0.8871906
```

*Note:* Maybe you can get the posterior distribution using the prior
$\mathsf{Beta}(5, 5)$ and the same likelihood function, and see what
difference that alternate choice of prior distribution makes in the
point and interval estimates.

Answer (score -1):

With a typical coin it is quite unreasonable to assign a uniform distribution on the interval from $0$ to $1$ as the probability distribution of the frequency with which "heads" appear. For example, the uniform distribution would mean that there is a $10\%$ chance that "heads" appear more than $90\%$ of the time and there is a $10\%$ chance that "heads" appear less than $10\%$ of the time. That is not reasonable as applied to any normal coin. So you have to take it as a given in the math problem that is set here.

The physicist Edwin Jaynes has argued that this is a reasonable prior when you know that "heads" and "tails" are both possible outcomes but you know nothing else. That is certainly different from the situation with most coins.